# Rails - Stripe "Amount" formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have created a Stripe Customer and associated them to a plan.  On the profile page I would like to show them the plan details.  However in Stripe API my $50.00 price renders as 5000 and when i attemp

```
`Price: <%= number_to_currency( current_user.amount) %>'
```

I get $5,000.

Is there anyway to make this render $50.00 instead of the $5,000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `number_to_currency` helper method. What I mean to say is that number_to_currency method does not change any value ( yes until you specify precision ). you can find the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency). Actually the value of `current_user.amount` is `5,000` and I am assuming the `amount` is of type string

The only way you will be able to get it print $50.00 instead of $5,000 is if you do something like this

`Price: <%= number_to_currency( current_user.amount / 100) %>` if amount is number

or

`Price: <%= number_to_currency( current_user.amount.gsub(',','').to_f / 100) %>` if amount is string

Comment: Price: <%= number_to_currency( current_user.amount / 100) %>
works great. thanks!

Comment: ha, how do i do that? im fairly new to stackO

Comment: there should be a tick sign appearing just below the votes up/down icons . you will have to click that to mark it as accepted.